# Pygame Mixer music (multiple music tracks)

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I have a quite simple question but surprisingly did not find a duplicate.

I have 2 music tracks for my game and want to switch fom the first music to something else before it runs out naturally.

```
mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
mixer.music.queue("music_phase2.mp3")
mixer.music.play(1, 0.0, 3000)
```

Normally i can use music.queue to go to the next music track. But i want the first music to stop after a specific event (like a timer or counter) and immediately start the next track.

I thought of something like this but it didnt work.
(I need to mention that in my program i want to load the music within a while loop so maybe that is causing problems.)
This part of the code handles the music. The first music stops as it should afte the counterr reaches 10.
But the second music doesnt start to play (just silence).

```
from pygame import mixer
pygame.mixer.init()

running = True

mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
mixer.music.play(1, 0.0, 3000)

# main loop
while running:
    if logic.counter > 10:
        mixer.music.stop()
        mixer.music.unload()
        mixer.music.load('music_phase2.mp3')
        mixer.music.play(1, 0.0, 3000)


#code doesnt end here but the rest shouldnt influence the music
```

Comment: The example you've provided doesn't make sense. What is `logic`? Also, it's never updated. And why would the music stop after it reached `50` when the loop suggest it should stop after `10`? Please provide a proper [mcve]. If this is roughly how you code is, then there's a pretty clear reason to why this doesn't work, but without a proper [mcve], then it's just guess work.

Comment: Hi Ted, this is just a small portion of my code and logic is a different file which i imported. I didnt really know what the best way was to convey my problem so thats why its a bit of a mess. However Eladtopez was still able to help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your mistake.
You are doing:

```
while running:
    if logic.counter > 10:
        mixer.music.stop()
        mixer.music.unload()
        mixer.music.load('music_phase2.mp3')
        mixer.music.play(1, 0.0, 3000)
```

The problem is, the `logic.counter` keeps increasing! I don't see anywhere a flag or something inside the code that is supposed to stop the `logic.counter` from increasing!

This means that once the `logic.counter` reaches 11, it enters the `if` block. **However**, it will enter the `if` when it is 12 and re-load the music again. and again, and again. Forever. You need to change it to:

```
    if logic.counter == 10:
```

So it will unload the first music and load the second music only once.

Comment: Hi Eladtopaz. Thanks a lot for the help. Unfortunately i wasnt able to solve my problem however i was able to make the first music stop after the counter reached 50. But the second music didnt start playing. There might be some issue because it is within the while loop. But if i have the music functions outside the loop it doesnt work as well. I updated the question with my current code. Thank you

Comment: I just found the bug in the program, I updated my solution as well